# Validating an hibernate model against a database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, maven

I need to validate if a database schema is still valid according to the java classes annotated by hibernate entities.

Background : we want to migrate our production database with liquibase generated scripts + custom SQL scripts, and then assert if java/hibernate model is compliant with those changes before deploying the application server.

I have seen the hibernate maven plugin able to use hbm2ddl to update/create/drop a schema, but the VALIDATE option seems to be missing. Any suggestion with the maven plugin?

I have also seen in hibernate the SchemaValidator class with a validate() method that would be usefull, but since my ultimate goal is to validate the SQL migration scripts by the build server, I would prefer an existing maven plugin than wiring myself the schema validation in the build process.

Comment: Why don't you manually change hibernate ddl property to validate instead of doing it with a maven plugin?

Comment: Two reasons : (1) I would like to avoid manual change since it has to be integrated in our build cycle and (2) I prefer a simple model validation returning true/false instead of starting the complete server to read in logs if validation succeeded